# Application should not close, if update available

Tags: c#, auto-update

I'm using AutoUpdater.NET for updating my applications. It's a great library. My program collects data for inventory system-data, sent it to database and than close the application.

```
this.Close();
```

The problem is, that the program also close, if an update is available. I want, that the application stay open, until the user update or cancel. I know that I have to check, if update is available or update-form is open, but I don't know how. Could someone please help? (Sorry, I'm beginner)

```
AutoUpdater.Start(updatePath);
AutoUpdater.ShowSkipButton = false;
AutoUpdater.ShowRemindLaterButton = false;
AutoUpdater.Mandatory = true;
//AutoUpdater.UpdateMode = Mode.Forced;
AutoUpdater.RunUpdateAsAdmin = false;
var currentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
if (currentDirectory.Parent != null)
{
    AutoUpdater.InstallationPath = currentDirectory.FullName;
}
```

Comment: Does the form close before the application checks to see if there is an update?

Comment: I can see the update form for a moment, but than the application close. No change to interact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (in my case) was to replace Environment.CurrentDirectory with Application.StartupPath